# Javascript contact form not returning selected value from dropdown

Tags: javascript, contact-form

I have a contact form that is not returning the selected option in the generated email, it keeps saying "undefined."

This what I currently have (which I copied from one of the other working questions on the form).

```
var topic = $("select#topic").val();
    if (topic == "") {
        $("label#topic_error").show();
        $("select#topic").focus();
        return false;
    }

  var dataString = 'name=' + name + '&email=' + email +  '&message=' + message + '&topic=' + topic + '&phone=' + phone + '&address=' + address;
    //alert (dataString);return false;

    $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:"process.php",
        data:dataString,
        success:function () {
            $('#af-form').prepend("<div class=\"alert alert-success fade in\"><button class=\"close\" data-dismiss=\"alert\" type=\"button\">&times;</button><strong>Contact Form Submitted!</strong> We will be in touch soon.</div>");
            $('#af-form')[0].reset();
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

});

The html form of the item in question is this:

```
     <select name="topic" id="topic">
        <option value=""></option>
        <option value="General">General Information</option>
        <option value="Sessions">Signing up for Support Sessions</option>
        <option value="facilitator">Becoming a Facilitator</option>
      </select>
```

I have no idea what I'm doing with javascript so I'm having trouble even looking up the answer.  Can anyone tell me what I have wrong?

Comment: use `$('#dropdownid').val('selectedvalue');`

Comment: The javascript snippet you provided shows what you do if *nothing* is selected, but you're asking about why it's not working when you *do* have something selected...

Comment: If you put an event when changing the value from the select? Would that work for you?

Comment: Is it a typo `label` element inside `select` element?

Comment: @AlexKudryashev Yes that was a missplaced label, thanks.

Comment: @TylerRoper I've edited to include the rest of the javascript.

Comment: @MuntasirAlam Where would I put that code.  Sorry but I really have no idea what I'm doing with javascript.

Comment: Check my answer, I hope that helps

Comment: I think I need to add something to the "var dataString" section, but I don't know what code to use. I tried '&topic' + topic but that didn't work

Answer (score 0):

You can see the select value `onclick` like this

```js
$(document).ready(function(){ 
  $('#button1').click(function(){ 
    alert($('#combo :selected').text());
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="combo">
  <option value="1">Test 1</option>
  <option value="2">Test 2</option>
</select>
<input id="button1" type="button" value="Click!" />
```

If you want to send it these values to your email you can try a **POST** request like this.

```
<form method="post" action="process.php">
  <select name="taskOption">
    <option value="first">First</option>
    <option value="second">Second</option>
    <option value="third">Third</option>
  </select>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit the form"/>
</form>
```

**PHP**

```
<?php
   $option = isset($_POST['taskOption']) ? $_POST['taskOption'] : false;
   if ($option) {
      echo htmlentities($_POST['taskOption'], ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8");
   } else {
     echo "task option is required";
     exit; 
   }
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that does not help me get the selected item into the email along with the other content from the form.

Comment: Do you have an example of what you want? I'm a bit unclear on your needs. I thought you just wanted to get the value from the `<select>`

Comment: It is a contact form. On the contact form is a drop down with 3 options. When a user fills out the contact form it sends me an email telling me what they entered.  I can't get the values chosen in the dropdown to be sent via the email, it shows up as empty.  I think it might have something to do with this part of the `code`javascript code: var dataString =`code`   Does that make any more sense?

Comment: Added some PHP code you can try implementing that. Thats as far as I can probably help you, I get your question now, but if that does not work I suggest asking a new question and actuall writing that in, as your previous comment is much clearer than your question.

Comment: Google `POST` request for dropdown or `select`, a bunch of good resources there